# select where field equals one of multiple values

Tags: sql

I want rows but in `WHERE` I have different values. How can I get these rows? Let's say I want to check names of people with different `cnic` values?

```
select name from table where cnic='123','234','134';
```

It gives me an error. How can I do this?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the specifics of your question in the body rather than the subject. Also, what is the error meesage that you get?

Comment: Hint: `IN (...)`

Comment: Use IN... where cnic in ('123','234'...)

Answer (score 12):

use mysql In operator for checkinng multiple values.

```
select name from table `where cnic IN ('123','234','134');
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use the In operator for this
  `select name from table where cnic in ('123','234','134')`